# Aufbau's principle violation at the time of complex formation

Tags: coordination-compounds

[image: See the orbitals after 3d]
My doubt is why don't we write 4s orbital before 3d as it is lower in energy according to Aufbau's principle? (I'm getting this info from other sites that 3d comes before 4s in transition metals but I'm not pretty sure about this thing)

Further, why are 4p and 4d come directly after 4s? Should have 5s come before 4d according to Aufbau's Principle?

Please help me I'm very much confused

Comment: Because hybridisation in transition metal complexes is a load of bogus rubbish.

Comment: This might help: http://chemguide.co.uk/atoms/properties/3d4sproblem.html

Comment: If this hybridisation thing is rubbish in complexes how am I gonna understand complex formation? Can you explain this particular complex formation from some other theory?

Comment: Where did you get the image? Is that from a textbook? Even if you do use the concept of hybridization, it would be 2 of the 3d orbitals, not the 4d that are involved in bonding. If you look at the orbtial splitting diagram for an octahedral complex that only considers sigma interactions, you'll see three nonbonding orbitals that are from the metal 3d and two higher energy antibonding orbitals that are also mostly metal 3d. These two come about because two of the metal 3d orbitals contribute to bonding orbitals. The 4d's are not involved at all.